# Using CDATA in XML as Parameter

Tags: xml, postman

I have a soap request xml which takes a xml string as parameter. Using postman I am getting this error. Please help me to solve this issue. I tried many ways but failed.

[image]

Now, facing another issue after using CDATA suggested by @Yitzhak Khabinsky.

[image]

As you can see in the above picture I am getting "SUCCSS" message but the tpXmlData parameter which takes xml string always sending null while execution via postman.

Here is my SOAP Envelop:

[image]

Comment: You need to use a CDATA section just for the textual value inside an XML tag only. No need to use it for an XML fragment. For example, `<tag><![CDATA[whatever value]]></tag>`

Comment: @Yitzhak Khabinsky, Thanks!

Comment: Dear @Yitzhak Khabinsky, could you suggest the another issue of this topic after using CDATA as per your suggestion?

Comment: My understanding that you are trying to call a SOAP Web Service. You need to check its documentation to see what the service is expecting.

Comment: Please don’t include markup, code, or error messages as screenshots. Instead, copy them as text into your question and format them as code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please always provide source code, error messages and other textual information as inline plain text rather than external pictures. Text is searchable (it shows up in search results), reusable (you don't need to type it again) and normally easier to read (it displays in your device's preferred font).

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue like this:

```
<![CDATA[]]>
```